# How to display non-graphed data from CSV file in Highcharts' tooltip?

Tags: csv, highcharts, tooltip

How can I display data in the tooltip, which do not appear in the graph? That is, I have only this one bar chart, but more data in the CSV file. Now, I'd like to display in the tooltip not only the graphed data, but additional ones from the CSV file. Is that possible? And if so, how?

I prepared a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/vo76k9p5/3/).

The tooltip is like this here:

```
    tooltip: 
    {
        snap: 0  ,
        useHTML: true,
        padding: 0,
        formatter: function () 
        {
            return 'Year: ' + this.point.x + '</b><br />Annual mass balance: <b>' + this.point.y + ' m w.e.</b><br>Number of observed glaciers: ';
        }
    },
```

And the CSV reading is done here:

```
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {

    var series = {
        data: []
    };

    var temp = []

    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');

    // For each line, split the record into seperate attributes
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');

        if (lineNo !== 0) {
            var x = +items[0],
                kwh = parseFloat(items[2]);
            if (!isNaN(kwh)) {
                series.data.push([x, kwh]);
            }
        }
    });

    // Push the completed series
    options.series.push(series);

    new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the  [fiddle updated with extra data in tooltip here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/vo76k9p5/5/)

Here you go:
put your data as {x:something, Y:something,extra:ExtraInfoToshowe} as below:

```
 $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');

        if (lineNo !== 0) {
            var xValue = +items[0],
                kwh = parseFloat(items[2]);
            if (!isNaN(kwh)) {
                series.data.push({x:xValue,y: kwh, extra:items[3]}); //here I changed
            }
        }
    });
```

And in the tooltip formatter function , call that extra thing you want as below :

```
 formatter: function() {
            return 'Year: ' + this.point.x + '</b><br />Annual mass balance: <b>' + this.point.y + ' m w.e.</b><br>Number of observed glaciers: '+this.point.extra;
        }
```

Comment: Great, that did the trick. Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea why the negativeColor in the series does not work?

Comment: Change your plot-options as below code , Also remove color from series{}  

plotOptions: {
            series: {
                connectNulls: false,
                shadow: false,
                lineWidth: 2,
           color: '#7994d9',
            negativeColor: '#ff6c7f',
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }